# Шифрование паролей в CMS

Tags: wordpress, joomla, cms, dle, mysql

Какими алгоритмами шифруются пароли в БД DLE, WP, Joomla ?

Comment: кого ломать собрались?))
там не шифрование а хэширование, если я правильно вопрос понял)

Comment: `MD5($pass)` вроде бы везде. В джумле точно.

Comment: Ломать никого не собрался ) Перенести пользователей нужно )
В джумле точно md5($pass,$salt)
Где кстати соль джумлы?) Не подскажете?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

соль жумлы в configuration.php . и у всех систем выше названиых система md5($pass.$salt) а вообще для того что бы это узнать посмотрите файл модели добавления пользователей